# probability distribution of communities in Stochastic Block Model

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, graph-theory

Consider a simple case of [Stochastic Block Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_block_model#Definition): all nodes in the graph are equally divided into two communities, the probability of edge connection for nodes in the same community is $p$, nodes in different communities $q$. Given a node $v$, consider the random variable $\Delta(v)$: the difference of numbers of neighbors in the two communities. I am wondering how to calculate the probability distribution of $\Delta(v)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ denote those communities. Also let $N_j(v):=\{w\in C_j:w\leftrightarrow v\}$. Assume that $v\in C_1$. Then for $0\le x< |C_1|$ and $0\le y\le |C_2|$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(N_1(v)=x)=\binom{|C_1|-1}{x}p^x(1-p)^{|C_1|-x-1}
$$
and
$$
\mathsf{P}(N_2(v)=y)=\binom{|C_2|}{y}q^y(1-q)^{|C_2|-y}.
$$
Consequently, the distribution of $\Delta(v):=N_1(v)-N_2(v)$ is determined by
$$
\mathsf{P}(\Delta(v)=z)=\sum_{y}\mathsf{P}(N_1(v)=z+y)\mathsf{P}(N_2(v)=y).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's a straightforward calculation. I am wondering how to give a simplified estimation of the result (it can depend on some favorable values of $p$ and $q$).

Comment: @luw Unless $p=q$ I don't think that there is a nice expression for that pmf.